# C filter file input stream

Tags: c, stream, stdin

I'm using a third party library in C that takes `FILE *` as a data source and does some processing on the text.

Right now, I just pass `stdin` or `fopen` a file and pass that.

But, I want to do some filtering before the library sees the text. (Specifically, I want to insert a semicolon `;` before each new line character `\n` or `\r`.)

What's the best way to do this in pure C (not C++) without copying the whole file into memory at once (i.e. as some kind of pipeline)?

This is how I call the library

```
mpc_result_t r;
FILE *f = NULL;
if (argc > 1) {
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
} else {
    f = stdin;
}
if (!f) return;

if (mpc_parse_pipe("test", f, test, &r)) {
    mpc_ast_print(r.output);
    mpc_ast_delete(r.output);
} else {
    mpc_err_print(r.error);
    mpc_err_delete(r.error);
}
fclose(f);
```

Comment: we'd have to see some code sample where you call the library.

Comment: You can read the while input into a file, and then pass that file into the library.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by *pure C*? C doesn't have a notion of pipeline. Instead, you can write to a temporary file the transformed input, and then provide that temporary file as input to your library. (Ok, what @2501 said...)

Comment: Otherwise, you can use POSIX or other system specific constructs to allow a separate process perform then transformation while the library reads the transformed output concurrently.

Comment: I agree with @jxh: I don't think you can do it using 'pure C' as defined in the C11 standard without using a separate pass over the data — effectively reading from the original input and writing to a file, and then passing that file to the library function.  If you can use POSIX, then you have options — your mapping code could be run in a separate process with pipes, for example, or perhaps in a separate thread.  Make sure you know what you'll do with CRLF line endings.  Taken at face value, you'd add a semicolon before the CR and another before the LF, but that might not be the best choice.

Comment: If the library works on a pipe (and it probably does), just create a pipe, use `fdopen` to create a FILE * and feed the transformed data into the pipe.  This is not "pure C", but is probably what you're looking for.  I don't understand why you say "as some kind of pipeline" is equivalent to "copying the whole file into memory at once"; they are completely different, and using a pipe will certainly not copy the whole file into memory. (Unless the file is small enough to fit into the pipe, but if that's the case it's kind of irrelevant.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The library is probably making blocking I/O calls, and so the main process will not get a chance to write into the pipe when the library call is blocked. This is why concurrency is likely needed with a pipe solution. C does not define an asynchronous mode of operation for FILE operations.

Comment: I should explicitly state that the data should be fed into the pipe by a child, not from the main process.  Yes, concurrency is almost certainly needed.